# Batch Calculator not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch and am practicing by making a calculator.  I've made it but its not working.  So I want to check with more experienced people to see whats wrong.

```
@echo off

set MATH=Equation:
set /a result=%MATH%
echo %result
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do set /p instead of just set (set /p means user input)
if you were to do that it would look like this

```
@echo off
title CALCULATOR

:start
cls
set /p MATH=Equation:

set /a result=%MATH%
echo %result%
pause
goto :start
```

Comment: stack over flow only allows a certain amount of lines I guess.  Pause should be one line lower and goto :start should be below pause

Comment: Thanks Pixel Piggy, I'm really new to batch XD

Comment: @PixelPiggy no. You need to indent all your code with 4 spaces.

Comment: Nope, you can and it works the same but it still works without doing it

Comment: Ohhh you meant on the post.  Sorry dude.